# Migrate from Google Authsub token to Oauth2 Token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, authsub

i have stored Google Authsub token in my database to upload video on their YouTube Channel. i have used Zend Gdata library for this. Google is removing Authsub feature in April 2015.

is there anyway to migrate my all Google Authsub token to OAuth2 token ?

Thanks!

Comment: I am in this same predicament...  Years ago I created an App which accessed Analytics data.  And initially I used AuthSub but then transitioned to oAuth.  While I "encouraged" users to migrate to oAuth if they ever came back to my site, I never sent them emails indicating they would need to re-authorize or at some point I would not be able to access their data.  I was never sure if this deprecation policy only applied to new accounts or if eventually the tokens would no longer work.